# Query only once with Django Rest Framework

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I'm obtaining data from database and display on table via jQuery and Django Rest Framework(DRF). Also, I'm using pagination. The problem is that every time I click "next" or "previous" button on table, `get_queryset()` is called and DRF make the query again and again which slows down pagination. How can I save/cache this query result so pagination doesn't query every time I use pagination?

## DRF Implementation in view

```
class SomeListing(generics.ListAPIView):
    pagination_class = ResultsSetPagination
    serializer_class = ResultSerializer
    
    def get_queryset(self):
        param = self.request.query_params.get('param', None)

        query = some_function_to_get_data(self.request, param)

        return query
```

Comment: Query needs to be done for pagination eg. 1-10 on page 1 and when you click "next" the table fetch page 2 (eg. from 11- 20). DRF doesn't cache queryset by default. DRF caching: [link](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/caching/)

Comment: Thank you. How can I set the query for each page?

Comment: [DRF Pagination](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/pagination/#pagenumberpagination)

Comment: Thanks again. I already have pagination and 10 rows per page limit but I don't know which parameter I should use to limit the query. If there are 50 rows in database, I just want to get first 10, then second 10 etc.

Comment: You can set the `PAGE_NAME` attribute, as described here: https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/pagination/#setup